# Section indexes in UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

Is it possible to add indexes of sections ON the tableview and change the position of the right bar, or change it's Y position?
i want it to be: 
[image]

Now it is like:

[image]

And it changes the width of my tableview. I want the full width.

Comment: Position of indexes depends of your array sorting.

Comment: I mean the X position of the whole right bar

Comment: Not sure but I think Apple forbids changing the possision of such component. If you really need to move it to left you can try to get the corresponding view from self.view tree using: for(UIView *v in self.view.subview) {}